# Monitor child processes of a process

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm running .exe file using this code:

```
Process proc = Process.Start("c:\program.exe");
proc.WaitForExit();
```

If I start `Stopwatch` before starting the process and stop it after `proc.WaitForExit();` line, I can get the time that user was using that particular program.

The problem I'm facing is that some programs (and games) use launchers - some small .exe file that usually checks something and then launches another .exe file that is actually the program/game that the user wants to run. In these cases the code above doesn't work because it returns after launcher exists.

How can I track all processes that `proc` runs, and wait unitl all of them are terminated?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: Unfortunately not :( I don't know process's name.

Comment: +1 for the extension method.

Comment: @xx77aBs you should post your solution as an answer, and not as part of the question. I'm posting it as a community-wiki, feel free to post your own "duplicate" answer and leave a comment under the community-wiki answer asking it to be deleted as it is a dup of your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this - [Find all child processes of my own .NET process / find out if a given process is a child of my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189117/find-all-child-processes-of-my-own-net-process-find-out-if-a-given-process-is) or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d60f0793-cc92-48fb-b867-dd113dabcd5c/how-to-find-the-child-processes-associated-with-a-pid. They provide ways to find child processes by a parent PID (which you have).

You can write monitor the process you create and also get its children. You could then track everything, and wait for them all to finish. I say "try" because I'm not sure you could catch very rapid changes (a process starting others and then dying before you get his children).

Comment: Thanks, I've checked the links that you gave me and managed to create good solution using PIDs :)

Answer (score 36):

Here is the solution that the asker found:

```
// using System.Management;
public static class ProcessExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Process> GetChildProcesses(this Process process)
    {
        List<Process> children = new List<Process>();
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID={0}", process.Id));

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
        {
            children.Add(Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"])));
        }

        return children;
    }
}
```

**[Updated]**

Slightly more modern code:

```
// using System.Management;
public static class ProcessExtensions
{
    public static IList<Process> GetChildProcesses(this Process process) 
        => new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                $"Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID={process.Id}")
            .Get()
            .Cast<ManagementObject>()
            .Select(mo =>
                Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"])))
            .ToList();
}
```

Comment: using System.Management;

Comment: I have an Excel application with 5 workbooks showing in Task manager. But while supplying Excel process it doesn't give any child process!

Answer (score 1):

you can't wait for process(B) another process(A) is running, if that process(A) isn't waiting for the process(B). what you can do is track the process using `Process.GetProcessesByName()` if you know it's name

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help me. I don't know the name of the exe file that is going to be run. That's why I need to somehow get all processes that proc has started.

Comment: in that case you can track the active processes before and after you ran the program... it's not a good way, but it's the only one you can use

Comment: I've thought of that, but it's not very reliable. I'll try to find a better solution, and if I don't find it, I'll maybe track just the processes whose executable file is located in the same folder as the launcher, or something like that.