# Get all Main Window Titles of the SAME PID

Tags: c#, powershell

Have tried to get all main window titles of the same pid, but without luck.
The main issue is that all Citrix Receiver connections are running on 1 PID, and therefore despite i have 2 Citrix windows in Task Manager, it is showing only the first one as being available. Both processes are running only under 1 PID.

*** How can I get all the opened Window Titles of the same process CDViever.exe? 1 PID ==>Many Processes with Window TItles.

PS They appear in TASK Manager, but whenever i retrieve the data in powershell or C# it is showing only the first main window title.

The c# code:

```
 Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} Window: {2}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id, theprocess.MainWindowTitle);
                Console.WriteLine("Window: {0}", theprocess.MainWindowTitle);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

The powershell code i used is:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle} | Format-Table Id, Name, mainWindowtitle,IncludeUserName -AutoSize
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not a child process -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922725/monitor-child-processes-of-a-process

Comment: 1 PID == 1 Process, no such thing as multiple simultaneously running processes with the same PID.