# How to kill process with entire process tree with Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, process

This is the working C# code I would like to mimic in Python.

```cs
var process = Process.Start("wt", "-w 001");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
process.Kill(entireProcessTree: true);
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(["wt", "-w 001"])
time.sleep(2)
process.kill()
```

Comment: Yes, I know but it's totally possible with C#. So It should have a way to do it in Python.

Comment: It is possible with limitations in C#, and the limitation is that no non-leaf process in the tree has died.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows does not maintain a process tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189117/find-all-child-processes-of-my-own-net-process-find-out-if-a-given-process-is/47274925#47274925), so killing child processes will not always work if the process structure has been broken, e.g. because a process only acts as a "launcher" and then terminates itself.

Specifically it will not work for [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) since `wt.exe` will launch `WindowsTerminal.exe` and then terminate itself. `WindowsTerminal.exe` launches `wsl.exe` and `conhost.exe` which are both terminated. Finally there will be 3 processes left: `OpenConsole.exe`, `powershell.exe` and `WindowsTerminal.exe`.

That said, [psutil.Process.children](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.children) to the rescue:

```
import psutil
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["wt", "-w 001"])
children = psutil.Process(process.pid).children(recursive=True)
for child in children:
    child.terminate()  # friendly termination
_, still_alive = psutil.wait_procs(children, timeout=3)
for child in still_alive:
    child.kill()  # unfriendly termination
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with wt (Windows Terminal), maybe because it is not a win32 application?

Comment: @0lan: no, because `wt` is a launcher app for `WindowsTerminal` and then terminates itself, which breaks the process tree.